# Is the term "breadwinner" still widely accepted?

Tags: word-choice

In my country, the term **breadwinner** is widely used. However, several years ago, if I remember it correctly, some TV personality said that the term **breadwinner** is not anymore the usual term to call a person who primarily earns for the family. If this word is not widely accepted nowadays, what word would be rather used?

Comment: I think you are from the Philippines. Dear, if it is perfectly understandable here in in our country, I see no reason why choosing another term would be more proper.

Comment: Hi @gelolopez. Yes, you're right. However, I am not too sure of the word's popularity here in our country. :)

Comment: It is quite obvious. Professionals in our country use the word to describe themselves as the primary, if not the only, earner of the household. Using breadwinner provides no confusion so there is no problem in using it.

Comment: Actually, without hearing it on TV, I would stick with breadwinner. I am just asking if there is a newly used word nowadays, not just here in our country, but also in other English-speaking countries. Thanks for commenting, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael said, breadwinner is alive and well in British English. In American English, breadwinner (though still right up there) is falling in use (less than half the British use, and falling; if you use the Ngram, extend to 2013). The word is being replaced by "primary wage earner".

Quite a hubbub was created here recently when a Pew study showed that in 40% of households, women are the primary wage earners.

Comment: I've deleted my answer (and changed the default range on my Ngram Viewer), but it does show a similar drop in the use of 'breadwinner' in UK usage as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Pew Research study mentioned in another answer is titled (ironically enough), "[Breadwinner Moms](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2013/05/29/breadwinner-moms/)." I would agree another answer that the demise of *breadwinner* is exaggerated.

While [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) does seem to show that the use of *breadwinner* has tailed off somewhat in recent years, charting *breadwinner* vs *primary wage earner* in Google Ngrams for American English shows that *breadwinner* is still used [much more frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breadwinner,%20primary%20wage%20earner&year_start=1900&year_end=2013&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,breadwinner;,c0;.t1;,primary%20wage%20earner;,c0).